# Start the Rsync daemon to synchronize a directory between two servers

Tags: sync, services, rsync

I want to synchronize a directory on the server A to a server B.

On the server A I created a file `rsyncd.conf` with the content:

```
uid             = rsync
gid             = rsync
use chroot      = no
pid file        = /var/run/rsyncd.pid

[share]
  comment = share
  path = /etc/dirtosync
  read only = false
  list = yes
  hosts allow = *
  auth users = rsync
  secrets file = /etc/rsyncd.secrets
```

And I created on the server A the file `/etc/rsyncd.secrets` with the content:

```
rsync:rsync
```

I also created on the server A  the pid file, and the user rsync with the password rsync.

On the server A, on the file: `/etc/default/rsync` I put the value `RSYNC_ENABLE` to `true` and I started the rsync daemon with the command:

```
/etc/initd/rsync start
```

On the server A and the server B the owner and the group of the directory is rsync.

I launched on the machine B the command:

```
rsync -avzr rsync@<serverA>:/etc/dirtosync/* /etc/dirtosync/
```

I also tried on the server A the command

```
rsync -avzr /etc/dirtosync/* rsync@<serverB>:/etc/dirtosync/
```

With this two commands the result is the same: the files are synchronized just one time when I launch the command but after if I modify the files in the server A they aren't synchronize to the server B

Do I have to do something else to keep the file synchronized?

Comment: Check this tutorial for rsync daemon service: https://www.atlantic.net/cloud-hosting/how-to-setup-rsync-daemon-linux-server/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misunderstand how rsync works. rsync does not automatically replicate changes - it is not like dropbox or similar software. rsync only synchronises files once each time it is run. If you want to synchronise more often, then put the rsync command in a cron script (eg. look in */etc/cron.daily*). If you want something that automatically synchronises changes, like dropbox does, then look at a different project, such as [Sparkle Share](http://sparkleshare.org/) or [ownCloud](http://owncloud.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You may also use lsyncd: https://github.com/axkibe/lsyncd. I'm using so far and it's great for this.

Answer (score 0):

The `rsync` syntax you've posted works assuming you've omitted the machine's host name/IP, but does not use the `rsync` share you've set up.  To use the share, you would need to change your syntax as follows to use the share:

```
rsync -av rsync@MACHINE-A::share/ /etc/dirtosync/
```

However, that will still not set up a continual sync between those folders.  What you seem to be after is a bi-directional sync for those folders, which is something that you can either set up in the cron or start using [Unison file synchronization software](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/).

Unison is not well maintained any more, and I have not used it myself, but I have heard great things about it.  It keeps track of changes to files made in a directory that you've set up for synchronization, and periodically copies those files over using `rsync` or another (configurable) method.

If you're going to go the `rsync`-in-the-cron route, you will want to use the `-u` option which tells `rsync` to only copy over the newer files.  You will run into issues with deleted files re-appearing with this approach, however.